# Dynamic JTextArea which wait for user input like Netbeans Console

Tags: java, swing, reflection, stream, console

[image]

I am creating an IDE in swing where user can compile and run their java program. Here, output of the user's program will be shown to a `JEditorPane`. i am using reflection to do so.

I have set the input stream to a `JTextArea` by using `System.setIn()` and output stream to `JEdotorPane` by using `System.setOut()` method.

Now, the Problem is that when user run a program which have console input like `System.in.read();` it do't wait for user input, from `JEditorPane`. It just run the program and read whole data from `JTextArea`. and further process other line of code.

Now, i want that **the program output should wait for the user input and when user provide input in `JTextArea` and hit enter, then further processing of inputted text is done.**

**Another Way: via CMD**

Actually, its little bit complicated to make an JTextPane as dynamic windows... and i have to do some more research on this particular topic...

So for now, i just did some changes in the way of showing Output. i am creating a separate Process by using Runtime class and execute that process in Command Prompt(CMD).

So, when the program generates an output. it shown on the command prompt... like many IDEs supports this mechanism... for example... Code Block.

for now, Its working fine...

Comment: please show us code, we cannot give you any satisfactory answer by guessing your code.

Comment: Your output hasn't been redirected. Please redirect the `System.out` and `System.in` to point to your console window's provider

Comment: @Aniket, i have just redirected input stream to `JTextArea` as i have written in the question, My problem is that **how do the program wait for user input when console input terms occurs in the program while  program is running?**

Comment: netbeans just spawns another thread that actually runs the program, and then redirects the System.out and System.in to receive data from a JTextArea. See `pipes` http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273874-redirect-systemin-to-jtextarea/

Comment: You should check this link: http://crownlessking.com/projects/gui_console_input_output_in_java_jtextarea

Comment: can you post part of the code at least

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) to listen for updates to the `JTextArea`.

From there you can veto changes, or insert them only at the end of the document.  Also, it'll notify you when updates are made to the document so you can send them to your program. This should simplify your life.

I would strongly advise against using a KeyListener - they're very finicky with things like focus.

Here's an example of adding a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html)

```
    final Document d = textArea.getDocument();
    if(d instanceof AbstractDocument){
        ((AbstractDocument)d).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter(){               
            @Override
            public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException{
                //Only allow edits at end (yours will be more complicated)
                System.out.println("Called replace");
                if(offset == d.getLength()){
                    //Edit only goes through if the filter bypass is used
                    fb.replace(offset, length, text, attrs);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey why don't you check the source of the NetBeans Output window for "inspiration": [OutputTab.java](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/d97242035d58/core.output2/src/org/netbeans/core/output2/OutputTab.java)

look here also: [output2 src dir](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/d97242035d58/core.output2/src/org/netbeans/core/output2)

Answer (score 0):

hmm, you can probably process the enter key using a `KeyListener` (If you don't know, you should implement it in the gui (or component) class, and than add it to the component.) and than continue the processing of the rest of the program's input. I would think this:

```
    @Override
    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKey == e.VK_ENTER){
    processText();
    keepProcessing();

    }
```

I hope this helps! good luck.